# new bootstrap.js features stop the features of old one

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I use 'ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.min.js' but earlier I used 'ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.0.js' but now due to 'ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.min.js' the features of 'ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.0.js' not working. how should i resolve this?, I am using angular 1.5 version.

Comment: what version of angular do you have ?

Comment: I use angular 1.5 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use 'ui-bootstrap-1.1.2.js' which have all features of 1.3.2 version and 0.14.0 version of 'ui-bootstrap'.